# My react website slows down after a number of re-renders

Tags: reactjs

I have recently started working in react.js and have implemented random div bars generation, by including a button that updates the *"useState"* values i.e. [value, setState], I update value with the setState function call on the click of a button, this works, but after about 12+ clicks of the button, the website slows down dramatically and I have no idea why it slows down.

```
    function Bars() {
    const [bars, setBars] = React.useState(getBars());
    document.querySelector("#Reset").addEventListener("click",()=>{setBars(getBars)});
    //the map function was not repeatedly adding divs to the screen
    return (
        <div id="dataContainer">
            {/* Returns multiple random bars randomly generated */}
            <div id="barContainer">
                {bars.map((height) => {
                    return (
                        <div class="sBar" style={{ height: height + 'px' }}></div>                        
                    )
                })
                }
            </div>
            <h1>{bars.length} bars to sort</h1>
            <div id="btnContainer"><button id="btnSort">Sort</button></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the code I use to generate the Bars, where the getBars function is simply a function that returns an array of heights to use in the return of this function. The handler on the *"#Reset"* is a button declared in another function that gets rendered before this, I want to keep them separate, but I am not sure if I am going about it in the right manner, separating the Menu function from this bar rendering function, as they are 2 different components.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're adding a bajillion event listeners

Comment: your code has some problems: 1) you should use `onClick` to add event for each element. 2) don't add `eventListeners` into component's body, you should use `useEffect` to handle them... i advise you, first of all read about JSX and component structure in React JS

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh ah okay, I had a feeling it was something to do with that, the issue is that Im trying to access data from another function, because I want it to occur on the menu, but its not linked to the bars function. Will take a look, thank you

Comment: @AdamKaminski use state to transfer data internally for your component

Answer (score 0):

```
function Bars() {
const [bars, setBars] = React.useState(getBars());
//the map function was not repeatedly adding divs to the screen
return (
    <div id="dataContainer">
        {/* Returns multiple random bars randomly generated */}
        <div id="barContainer">
            {bars.map((height) => {
                return (
                    <div class="sBar" onClick = {() => setBars(getBars)} style={{ height: height + 'px' }}></div>                        
                )
            })
            }
        </div>
        <h1>{bars.length} bars to sort</h1>
        <div id="btnContainer"><button id="btnSort">Sort</button></div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: This is adding it to each bar, I want to add it to a button in another function